# Is there any case where a relative adverb could also be described as a relative pronoun?

Tags: terminology

**1/03/20: Edited to provide examples as suggested by jlawler.**

It's a pretty straight forward question.

**Here are the definitions from SIL:**

**Relative Pronoun**

Definition: A relative pronoun is a pronoun that

- marks a relative clause
- functions grammatically within the relative clause, and
- is coreferential to the word modified by the relative clause.

**Relative Adverb**

Definition: A relative adverb is a pro-adverb that marks a relative clause.

**Relative Clause**

Definition: A relative clause is a clause which describes the referent of a head noun or pronoun. It often restricts the reference of the head noun or pronoun.

Here are links to defintions and discussion at YourDictionary.com

[relative adverbs](https://grammar.yourdictionary.com/grammar/adverbs/relative-adverbs.html)

[relative pronouns](https://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/pronouns/relative-pronoun.html)

It seems that the definition of a relative adverb is subsumed in the definition of a relative pronoun. So, I'm looking for examples where this distinction becomes clear and its usefulness is established.

Ok, so the distinction seems pretty straightforward with most of the words that are used to join relative clauses but not with *where, why* and *when*.

> **The church** *where* we were married **has burned down**.
>
> **Those times** *when* she is off her meds **cause great concern**.
>
> **The reason** *why* he left you **makes no sense**.

In these sentences, *where*, *when* and *why* mark an embedded relative clause that adds information (locative, explicative, descriptive) to the subject phrase without changing its basic meaning. They are conjunctive and have a clear pronomial relation to their antecedents, *the church*, *those times*, and *the reason*. They are adverbial *only* in as much as they modify the verb *in* the relative clause.  These are clearly relative pronouns, but I would not call them relative adverbs because they are not adverbial in their relation with the main verb, and because even if adverbs can modify nouns, these adverbs haven't changed the interpretation of the subjects; the church is just a church, and so on. These words refer to their antecedents and join them to a descriptive clause, making the relation they establish adjectival, not adverbial. They are also adjuncts.

Within the relative clause, they're just adverbs, as they are in questions like, *Why did he leave you?* and *Where were you married?* and so on. But they do seem to be taking the role of a preposition, as some commenters have suggested, where the clause is functioning as an object. But do prepositions really have a pronomial feature?  Not so sure about *where, why* and *when* as prepositions, and I'm hard pressed to find a dictionary that lists *preposition* as a (PoS) for these words. But I get it, so that's another way of looking at these relations.

So anyway, by these definitions - *where, why* and *when* in the above sentences are not relative adverbs.

In the following sentences they seem adverbial but do not introduce a relative clause, strictly speaking - they are predicate adjuncts.

> **They found the ball** where the dog had dropped it.
>
> **I love the church** *where* we were married.
>
> **I am concerned** about those times *when* she is off her meds.
>
> **Your cheating is the reason** *why* he left you.

These relations seem to be with the the whole predicate phrase, *found the ball*, and so on, in as much as the clause does not have and independent relation with the main verb or its object complement. So, I don't think *where* qualifies as a relative adverb, nor is this a relative clause because it is not strictly about the ball (maybe).

Here are the examples from YourDictionary.com for relative adverbs:

**When:**

> **Gone are the days** when I could stay up all night.

This is an inverted copular clause - *Gone* is a past participle adjective, ***The days*** when I could stay up all night **are gone**, *Gone* is a subject complement - *when* is either a relative pronoun, or it's functioning like a prepostion (*in* which) with a clausal object. A similar argument could be made for the following examples.

> **The 50s were a time** when the family unit was largely intact.
>
> **That is the year** when we got married.

**Where:**

> **We danced** [by the table] [where (at which) we could see the view].

The bolded text is the core sentence, the phrases in brackets are independent adjuncts. *Where* is locating the action so it is cleary adverbial in relation to the main verb, but it is also describing the location of the subject, and the table, it takes *the table* as its pronomial referent, and it is conjunctive/ prepositional. It has all these properties, so why narrowly insist that it is a relative adverb?

Similar arguments could be made for the following examples:

> **This is the coffee shop** where we'll find the best cup o' joe.
>
> **This is the garden** where they took their photos.

**Why:**

> **Her mass of library of books *is* the reason** why she's so well-spoken.

The main verb is copular, so similar arguments (as above) apply. The relative clause is an adjectival adjunct, and *why* is pronomial, conjunctive and prepositional (for which).

In the following examples I see no adverbial relation to the main verb, only a pronomial relation to its object complement:

> **Can you provide more information** why this conclusion is valid?
>
> **I have no idea** why he called.

As far as I can tell, in every case where one of these words is described as a relative adverb it could also, and perhaps more validly, be described as a relative pronoun. Is it called an adverb just because that's how these words are usually identified? SIL calls the relative adverb a pro-adverb which is just another way of saying that it's not really and adverb. I have a feeling that the term *relative adverb* is a bit bogus, it seems to be a distiction without a difference, unless someone can provide an example where one of these words is strictly and solely in an adverbial relation to the main verb and marking a relative clause, or at least a case where it makes a useful distinction. I can't think of or find one, and that's just me and I'm not an expert, but it seems impossible.

To answer my own question, I think it may always be the case with where, why and when that these relative adverbs can also be validly described as a relative pronoun. But I'm hoping someone can prove me wrong, otherwise, what's the use of this term?

Comment: Some confusion comes from using *adjective clause* for both *relative pronoun clauses* and *relative adverb clauses*.  *Relative pronouns* introduce *adjective (=adjectival) clauses*, but *relative adverbs* introduce *adverbial clauses*.  Both of these can be called *relative clauses*, but pronouns relate only to noun phrases and adverbs relate only to adverbial phrases.

Comment: So the difference is that realtive adverbs introduce a clause that modifes a verb phrase (finite or non-finite) and relative pronouns introduce a clause that modifes a noun, subject or object. Is that a correct statement? This would mean that they are always distinct. What they have in common is that they both introduce clauses and have this conjunctive property. Are relative pronouns and relative adverbs always conjunctive?

Comment: But here's the thing - SIL uses this example for a relative adverb: 'The street where you live.' In this case the clause is adding nformation to the noun *street*. It's an adjectival clause, right?

Comment: Yes!, but they aren't conjunctive when they aren't relative (used outside relative clauses), such as "Where is my pen", "Who took my pen", "That is my pen"...

Comment: In "The street where you live is bumpy", the relative clause does seem to be adjectival, but it isn't much different from "Where you live, the street is bumpy" which is clearly adverbial. (Thus the confusion.)

Comment: Ok, this is useful - I'm going to edit the question so it is more illustrative of this confusion. I am trying to answer this question on Quora: "Can a word function as a relative adverb and a relative pronoun simultaneously?" I'm beginning to think that the answer is yes, but with caveats. Also, it is a matter of analysis, which tends to be binary in linguistics (I think), so the idea that a word could be both is a sort of abstraction.

Comment: I think you mean 'both' rather than 'simultaneously', but "I" think the answer is NO.

Comment: Definitions are useless without examples.

Comment: @jlawler - I've provided several examples and discussed them. I hope you will find it worthwhile to respond to the question in more detail. I get a lot out of your insights, so it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

In English, the relative pronouns occupy the same positions as definite pronouns.  So, no, they are not adverbs.

Comment: So, in *I live where...* **where** seems to still have some pronomial aspect in as much as it refers to a place, even though it lacks a referent noun. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, that's a good point.  Maybe **where** is an adverb.  But maybe not.  **home** is just a NP, though it can have the force of a locational phrase.  "He stayed where I stayed -- namely home."

Comment: "Where" is best analysed as a preposition. e.g. "We must put it **where** no one will find it" = "We must put it **in a place where** no one will find it", where the prepositional interpretation is clear.

Comment: @BillJ, Yes, but let's make **where** a PP. Prepositional Phrase, rather than a preposition.  And your example verb, **put**, makes clear that the PP **there** in "We put it there" is a complement, not an adverbial modifier.  The verb **put** is subcategorized to require this complement, *"We put it".  Adverbs don't work this way, at least not ordinarily.  Modifiers are not obligatory.

Comment: Well, the POS of "where" is preposition. I take "where no one can find it" as a 'fused' PP construction with "where" as fused head-prenucleus, i.e. it is simultaneously head and (in this case) complement.

Comment: Incidentally, your point about complement / modifier demonstrates why the distinction between function and category (or class) is so important.

Comment: a) *I've hidden it that no one can find it* b) *I've hidden it in a place that no one can find [it]*--slightly malformed, though tolerable, in b) it seems that the last "it" refers to "place". Logically, this isn't even wrong, it works, but would not be understood like this when *where* were used, if *the thing* is frequently substituted for "it". Anyhow, in many grammars other than English "where it" makes perfect sense as a compound, I guess, haven't surveyed; just cp *id, quid, quot*, \*kwi-s, etc. Also cp *somewhere nb. can find*, **but not *\*in a place somewhere nb. can find*.**

Answer (score 3):

The differences between a relative pronoun and a relative adverb is in what role in the subordinate clause they correspond to. If the word acts at least a little like a pronoun in the relative clause (in English, relativizing words like "who" or "what"), then we call it a relative pronoun, and if it acts mostly like an adverb in that clause (in English, relativizing words like "where" and "when" and "why"), then we call it a relative adverb.

This might be a bit easier if we show a main clause corresponding to each type of relative clause.

Pronoun - Relative Pronoun

> **He** sees me - That's the man ***who** sees me*
>
> I see **him** - That's the man ***who** I see* (or, if you are using older forms of English, ***whom** I see*)
>
> **His** hat is blue - That's the man ***whose** hat is blue*

Adverb - Relative Adverb

> I live **there** - This is (the house) ***where** I live*
>
> I lived there **then** - That is (the time) ***when** I lived there*

English also has a third relativizer, the word **that**, which doesn't act like either type.

Comment: **that** is often treated as a relative clause introducer (in parallel with **that** in "the fact that he left"), since unlike real relative pronouns it must always be clause-initial.

Comment: By the way, **there** is not actually an adverb in "I live there".  It is a locational complement of **live**.

Comment: I would say that "adverb" is a syntactic category, while "locational complement" refers to the syntactic (and semantic) role, which is not mutually exclusive. It absolutely is acting more like a complement than like an adjunct, which sure is adverbs' prototypical role

Comment: The categorization system outlined here seems a bit inconsistent to me. If you categorize "where" as an adverb instead of as a pronoun because of its function (despite it being used with the noun phrase "the house" as an antecedent), then why don't you categorize "his" and "whose" as adjectives or determinatives instead of as pronouns (since they function as determiners of the word "hat" in your example sentences)?

Comment: @ewawem - Very good point. These words often do the work of conjunctions as well, and in come cases they can be adverbial, conjunctive and pronomial, all at once. But descriptive analysis tends to be binary, so one must decide at that point, what it is.  However, that decision doesn't obviate the fact that a word may also be displaying other functional characteristics.

Answer (score 0):

> I've decided to answer my own question here because I did the research and I think I've got it now. Thanks to the contributors for their helpful comments and answers.

Yes, some can, such as ***where*** and ***when***, but probably not without some pushback. I'm not sure that the distiction made by the term *relative adverb* is useful.

You can look up the definitions of these terms at SIL:

[Relative Pronoun](https://glossary.sil.org/term/relative-pronoun)

[Relative Adverb](https://glossary.sil.org/term/relative-adverb)

[Relative Clause](https://glossary.sil.org/term/relative-clause)

There are some good discussion here for both terms:

[Relative Pronoun](https://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/pronouns/relative-pronoun.html)

[Relative Adverbs](https://grammar.yourdictionary.com/grammar/adverbs/relative-adverbs.html)

But if you read carefully you will see that these two sources are not saying the same things.

Linguistic terminology can be quite confusing - there is a lot of interdependency where you need to understand other terms and concepts in order to understand just one. They are especially confusing in instructional grammar because linguistic terms often get misapplied, and adapted in different ways by different methods in langauge instruction. They even get used in different ways by linguists in different linguistic theories. There is widespread and often passionate disagreement in both fields over terminology. It’s a big mess, really, in as much as it is at best unhelpful to learners, and at worst confounding and misleading.

The most common relative pronouns are **who, whom, whose, which,** and **that**. Sometimes, **when** and **where** can be used as relative pronouns as well but this is subject to more debate, however plausible such analysis may be.

The most common 'relative adverbs' are **where, why** and **when**.

Relative pronouns and 'relative adverbs' are always conjunctive. Relative pronouns are used to join dependent relative clauses which are used to add information to nouns, subjects and objects. 'Relative adverbs' are also used to add information to *things* that signify time, place and manner (which may be the only reason they are called adverbs in terms of their relation to their antecedents), and usually have an adverbial relation to a subordinated verb.

Here’s the thing, these words are not only used as relative pronouns and relative adverbs. They have scope and can function in different ways in sentences. Sometimes they’re just adverbs, or conjunctions, or pronouns. And sometimes they seem to be functioning in more than one way at the same time, like *where* and *when*.

For example: *where*

> I live where the buzzards don’t fly. S|V|AC(clause)

*Where* introduces an adverbial clause - it’s not a 'relative adverb', because it modifies the **verb** *live*, not a noun, subject or object. It simply locates the action of the verb, making it an adverbial sentence complement phrase. One might say that *where* is a pronoun because it refers to a location, a thing, even though there is no anteceding referent. Infering a referent by ellipsis, doesn't make it so - there simply isn't one, which makes its relation one that localizes the action to *live*. It is not a relative pronoun nor a 'relative adverb' because the clause is not adding information to a thing (a noun, subject ir object). But it is conjunctive, so you could call it a conjunction but some experts dont like this. Others call it a conjunctive adverb, or just an adverb because it and its clause modify the main verb (time, place, manner). And still others, as demonstrated in the comments, would like to call *where* a preposition with a clausal object. I call it a conjunction (a word-level designation) because that is its primary role at the sentence level - it joins a dependent clause to the main clause as an adverbial sentence complement phrase.

> I live there. S|V|AC(avp)
>
> I live in NY. S|V|AC(pp)
>
> I live where the buzzards don’t fly. S|V|AC(clause)

The semantic structure is the same for all of these sentences - The subject lives *somewhere* (S|V|AC).

The clause is an adverbial sentence complement phrase - it says where the action happens. That’s all you really need to know. The difference is the word, phrase type or clause that is producing the adverbial relation. You can call it an adverb, a conjunctive adverb, a conjunction  or even a preposition, as is your prerogative, but it is not a 'relative adverb' (if there is such a thing), nor a relative clause in this use.

On the other hand…

> The house *where* she lives is very old.

*Where* introduces a relative clause that modifes the noun house - *where* is certainly a relative pronoun because it takes *house* as its referent and joins a relative clause that describes the subject. The relation *where* produces is pronomial and conjunctive, the relation of the clause to the subject is adjectival. *Where* is an adverb only because it has a relation to the verb *live* - it locates the action of this subordinated verb. But that relation is not to the subject, so why call it a 'relative adverb', which defines the relation to the subject, not to the subordinated verb?

> I remember the time *when* the steam pipe burst.

In these sentences, *where* and *when* have very clear and predominating pronimal and conjunctive features, refering to the *house* and the *time*, and establishing the relation between the subject and the subordinate clause. Whether they’re doing all this simultaneously is a matter of analysis, which tends to be binary - it’s either one or the other, not both at the same time. But yeah, the word has all three functions covered, go figure.

The main thing that relative pronouns and 'relative adverbs' have in common is that they are both conjunctive - they join dependent clauses to other words, phrases or clauses that are nouns, subjects or objects. This is their primary role. And they are also always pronomial.

Comment: There is no modification of the verb in your example (I live where ...). The concept of relative adverb is not necessary if you consider that there is an ellipsis. The argument of the verb is just omitted, because superfluous. So where is just a relative pronoun as who.

Comment: @amegnunsen - I disagree. The sentence *I live* carries just one meaning - *I am alive*, while with the sentence complement phrase, with or without ellipsis, the meaning of the verb changes, it is not understood as a statement of being alive, but rather a meaning more related to the activity of living in a particular place. That could be disputed of course, so I do take your point. I should find a better example (thanks) . Still, I don't think your criticism is particularly relevant to the larger context of what I've said, unless there's something you'd like to add.

Comment: I don't understand why you brought up the question of transitivity. You should keep in mind to comprehend language that the surface and underlying form are not only destined to describe the sound but all the linguistic system. Not everything is marked. I will just add SIL is not a reference in matter of Linguistics.

Comment: I think I misunderstood what you were getting at. Anyway, I didn't say *where* was a relative adverb, but it is not a relative pronoun either because its relation is with a verb, not a noun, subject or object. I didn't bring up transitivity, at least not explicitly, but the point of that sentence is to show that *when* is not a relative pronoun or a relative adverb, and the clause is not a relative clause. Whether there is ellipsis or not, is an interesting question but it is not relevant.  I'm sorry but I'm just a little bit lost as to what your point is.

Comment: @UbuEnglish I think what you say in the second post down is precisely the reason why *where* is not a relative adverb in a sentence like *I live where the buzzards fly*. I think the preposition analysis mentioned above is more plausible.

Comment: @JD2000 - That a bit hard for me to grasp, *where* as a preposition, which I think would require that *I live where the buzzards* could stand as a complete sentence. So why would *where* not be a conjunctive adverb + clause? Unless your saying that the entire clause is functioning as the object of the preposition. I tend to think in terms of word phrase relations, but I get that they get conjoined in a variety of ways which complicates analysis. I'm not a linguist - just an ESL instructor - trying to simplify grammar for my students. I go deep so I can go wide. But it's not easy.

Comment: Yes, I mean that the whole thing is one PP. If it's an argument of the verb (and IMO it clearly is) I don't see how it can be adverbial. I also find it bizarre to call this kind of construction a relative anything, because there's no antecedent - yes, it's possible to argue that there is a hidden antecedent, if you say that *I live where...* is short for *I live in a/the place where...*, but the only motivation I can see for saying that is to justify regarding it as a relative adverb, which makes this a circular argument.

Comment: @JD2000 - And for the record, I never said this sentence was an example of a relative anything, in fact I present the sentence as an example of what is not 'relative'. Whether it's a PP or not isn't really important. It's adverbial as a sentence complement phrase, which it would be no matter how you analyse the word *where*. Hope that makes sense.